# why does WordPress need two cookies for auth/login

Tags: authentication, cookies

I can see two cookies: auth and login cookies in wordpress. Why do we need two?
I think one is enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"On login, wordpress uses the wordpress_[hash] cookie to store your authentication details. It's use is limited to the admin console area, /wp-admin/

After login, wordpress sets the wordpress_logged_in_[hash] cookie, which indicates when you're logged in, and who you are, for most interface use.

Wordpress also sets a few wp-settings-{time}-[UID] cookies. The number on the end is your individual user ID from the users database table. This is used to customize your view of admin interface, and possibly also the main site interface."

[When in doubt, check the Codex first.](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies)

Comment: when I ask this question, there isn't a doc like now in wordpress codex :(

Comment: That page has been there since 6/21/05 - http://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=WordPress_Cookies&action=history (login to wordpress.org needed) and hasn't been altered for nearly 3 months.

Comment: This still doesn't answer why Wordpress needs two cookies. Both cookies authenticate you, why have one cookie for `wp-admin` and one cookie for other areas of the website?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the two cookies are to do with SSL. When using the admin area you want it secure and so you cannot have the authentication cookie details always presented to everyone on your site (such as non-SSL connections). However there are times you want to be known as logged in but not using the secure connection. So by separating them you can edit your site with the auth cookie details and remain logged in across the entire site with the logged in cookie.

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies